# Laying out labels & input with CSS/bootstrap

Tags: css

I'm wanting the two levels to be on the same row, each over their respective input. And I'm wanting the two inputs to be one the same row, under their respective labels. I'm rather bad with CSS/bootstrap and I'm struggling with this, currently my two inputs are way too long and on different rows.

```
{#Select a Role#}
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col">
                <label for="is_employee">Is Employee</label>
                <label for="dms_id">DMS Employee Code</label>
                <select id="is_employee" name="is_employee" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
                <input id="dms_id" name="dms_id" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

[image]

I was expecting the two inputs to be on the same row/line under the appropriate label.

Comment: I'd guess you're using bootstrap v5 but using v4 classes.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your Bootstrap version so according to the "Migrating to v5" [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/migration/#forms),

> Dropped form-specific layout classes for our grid system. Use our grid and utilities instead of .form-group, .form-row, or .form-inline.

So you could just make a 2 cols row :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-6">
    <label for="is_employee">Is Employee</label>
    <select id="is_employee" name="is_employee" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label for="dms_id">DMS Employee Code</label>
    <input id="dms_id" name="dms_id" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

You could adjust their size by setting the container `width` or `max-width`. You can use [Bootstrap classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/), `w-50` or `mw-50` for example.

Comment: I used your code snippet (except of the <link...> line and that worked,  thanks. Also used w-50 as well. It's looking a lot better. Any way I can push the 2nd label and input to the left a little closer to the first label and input? Thanks.

Comment: If you inspect `col-6`, you can see some padding added. You can change it with custom css or with `pl-0` (`padding-left:0`) for example. it seems that the Bootstrap 5 equivalent is `ps-0` . You can check the [v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) or [v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) doc.